# How to pass extras to a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a problem with passing extras to calls and catching them.

To make more clear what I intend to do:

Start a call and set extras for this intent.  This is what my current code for this looks like:

```
Intent dialIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +  this.number));
dialIntent.putExtra("foo", true);
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

I implement a BroadcastReceiver to "catch" the call and want to access the extra I set when starting the activity.  This is what I have in my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
  <intent-filter android:priority="1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Unfortunately the intent that is passed to my CallReceiver is a NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent.

I hope it's clear what I want to do and I hope it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a BroadcastReciever here you actually want to make another 'default dialer' activity but this one will have a higher priority to ensure it will be launched before the native dialer app.  Then you can alter the intent like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    Intent i = getIntent();
    //alter i here 
    startNextMatchingActivity(i);
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: i added this line above the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL action line: 

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />`

but it still doesn't work, i only receive the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL action

Comment: @Zoran Zaric try adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` as well

Comment: @Zoran Zaric I'm sorry I'm not sure what I was thinking.  The receiver isn't going to pick this up because you are calling startActivity not sendBroadcast.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Do you want to intercept all calls or just ones made from your app?

Comment: @schwiz both, first i want to intercept all calls, do something with them and make a new one.  The calls I (the app) do should be passed.

Comment: @Zoran Zaric I am not sure what you mean by the calls you make should be passed. But what you want to do to intercept calls is make an activity with no UI but the intent filter with action call.  Also set its priority to an extremely high number like max_int so you know it will be activated before the native dialer.

Comment: @schwiz ok I'll try to make more clear what I try to do. 1) the user makes a call with the normal phone app 2) my BroadcastReceiver intercepts this call and decides to 3a) pass the call to the default dialer or 3b) alter the number, do some more stuff and pass it to the default dialer.  I hope this clarifies it.  How would I "pass" a call intent to the native dialer when having a activity with an intent filter for action call with a very high priority?

Comment: @Zoran Zaric ahh ok I edited my original answer thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @schwiz ok i tried that, but it doesn't work.  I added this intent-filter to my activity: `<intent-filter android:priority="900001">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         </intent-filter>`  and removed the BroadcastReceiver, but now when i make a call the native dialer app receives the call.  thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: @Zoran Zaric I am at a loss, try to use apk tool http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/ to read the dialer's manifest and make sure you picked a higher int, and for the hell of it try setting the priority to 0 maybe I got it backwards...

Comment: @schwiz The Phone app is open source.  This is the Manifest: https://gist.github.com/70dd9794baec9fd689f8 I think lines 129-139 are interesting for me and the are pretty much how i had it.  I had to add `<data android:scheme="tel" />` to the intent filter, now it works! thanks a lot!!!