# android add extra and call programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to make a call through my app by putting extra data and while but I am unable to receive that data during the call can some explain where I am wrong below is my code for making call and receiving call

```
String uri = "tel:"+my_name;
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
        callIntent.putExtra("data", "mynewdata");
        callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

And call receiver

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            showToast(intent.getExtras().getString("data"));
        } 

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) { 
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver**Call State=" + state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                if(recieveCall){

                }
                Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver**Idle");
            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) { 

            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) { 
            // Outgoing call
            String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **Outgoing call " + outgoingNumber);

            setResultData(null); // Kills the outgoing call

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **unexpected intent.action=" + intent.getAction());
        }
          }
    }
```

I'm receiving call perfectly and even broadcast is working perfectly but I am not getting data from intent "intent.getExtras().getBoolean("data")"

Comment: Actually you are passing the data to Intent.ACTION_CALL and that data can be fetched in Intent.ACTION_CALL only using getIntent(). Broadcast you are receiving is for some other thread which doesn't contain the intent data you gave it. Intent you are receining in the broadcast is not the same intent you are passing. You need to pass the data in some other way.

Comment: Try like this `Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("data");`

Comment: Or `intent.getStringExtra("data"));`

Comment: Vijay, this will also not work, because what intent she is passing to the Intent.ACTION_CALL is not the same intent she is getting in BroadCastReceiver.

Comment: @RahulRaina its the same intent

Comment: @Vijay i tried both the way its not woking

Comment: So.. Have to agree with Rahul..

Comment: May be this will help you..(Link)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239712/how-to-pass-extras-to-a-broadcastreceiver]

Comment: Well i will rate +10 this question because it is very good concept of intent to understand... Good ankita, keep posting more questions.

Comment: Do you need the solution for this problem?

Comment: This thing can be implemented in way other than using Intent. You can implement it using: Constant-Class

Comment: @RahulRaina can you give me example

Comment: @AnkitaBansal, see i have  posted code in answer... its working. hope i solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here you need to create a java file (lets name it Constants.java):*

```
public class Constants
{
 public static boolean data;
 public static String str = "";
}
```

Now see the changes i did in the project along with the comments.

```
String uri = "tel:"+my_name;
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
        Constants.data = true; /*see change, set data in Constants.data*/
        Constants.str = "some data to pass..."; /*see change*/
        callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Now in broadcast receiver see the changes done...

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null && Constants.data) { /*changes done, get boolean from the Constants.data*/
            showToast("hi i have recieve");
            showToast(Constants.str); /*changes done*/
        } 

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) { 
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver**Call State=" + state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                if(recieveCall){

                }
                Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver**Idle");
            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) { 

            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) { 
            // Outgoing call
            String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **Outgoing call " + outgoingNumber);

            setResultData(null); // Kills the outgoing call

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **unexpected intent.action=" + intent.getAction());
        }
          }
    }
```

*Hope this solved your problem of how to pass data*

Comment: let me try this wait a min

Comment: for more help on android programming you can also visit my blog: http://rahulraina09.blogspot.com/